# How to whitelist outlook junk mail using Java

Tags: java, outlook-restapi, whitelist

I have to whitelist emails in outlook using java. Is there any option to whitelist emails Id's using java code

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you mean.  Do you mean stand-alone Outlook or Office365?  Do you mean the deprecated Outlook API?  What you mean by email "id"?

Comment: But I suspect the answer is that it is not supported; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/426256/outlook-api-junk-email.html

Comment: @StephenC I have a list of emails in the junk folder, I have to whitelist some of the senders using javax mail or outlook API. Currently, we are doing it by EWS  API (java), but due to the deprecation of EWS API, I am searching for a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is that what you are doing will not be supported.

You are using the EWS API which is deprecated.  According to [Upcoming changes to Exchange Web Services (EWS) API for Office 365](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ba-p/608055), the replacement is the Microsoft Graph API.

However it says:

> "While EWS and Graph have mostly overlapping functionality, there are some differences. **If you rely on an EWS API that does not have a Graph counterpart, please let us know via UserVoice of features needed for your app scenarios.**".

I scanned the Graph and could find nothing that matched what I think you are doing.  I also found [this Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/426256/outlook-api-junk-email.html):

> Q: Outlook API - Junk email
>
> Is there any way through the Outlook 365 API to see the "Blocked sender and > domains" list as it shown in the GUI settings under "Junk email"<sup>1</sup>?
>
> A: Afaik no, not currently. You can use PowerShell though.

The reply is from a Microsoft MVP, so I would be inclined to believe what he says.  (But if you don't ... feel free to read the Graph API documentation thoroughly, and come to your own conclusions.)

---

The fact that you are using Java is not going to change this.  It is the underlying RESTful APIs that are being deprecated.

---

<sup>1 - This is is not exactly what you are proposing, but I would be hugely surprised if the Graph API allowed you to add or remove blocked domains but not see the current list of blocked domains.</sup>